# barcode scanner closes at once, popup doesnt show

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, barcode-scanner

i'm trying to show an alert box on button click using this code in controller.js:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', ['ionic','ngCordova'])

.controller('page1Ctrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$cordovaBarcodeScanner'
```

function ($scope, $stateParams, $cordovaBarcodeScanner) {

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

$scope.scanCode = function()
{
   $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan(
   function (result) {
      alert("We got a barcode\n" +
            "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
            "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
            "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);

  }, 
   function (error) 
   {
      alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
   }
 );
}

});

}])
```

but when i run the app in the device, the scanner works but the alert box displaying the details doesn't show up, and the scanner closes at once after detecting a barcode. what could be the problem?

Comment: I guess you're implementing it wrong way. Try http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/barcodeScanner/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following way as mentioned in [Documentation](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/barcodeScanner/)

```
$cordovaBarcodeScanner
  .scan()
  .then(function(barcodeData) {
    // Success! Barcode data is here
    alert("We got a barcode\n" +
        "Result: " + barcodeData.text + "\n" +
        "Format: " + barcodeData.format + "\n" +
        "Cancelled: " + barcodeData.cancelled);
  }, function(error) {
    // An error occurred
  });
```

Regards.